# How to morph complicated svg shapes

Tags: html, animation, svg

I want to morph to very complicated shapes in svg.
They are consist of multiple paths.
Is it even possible?

I've already tryed something like this:

```
<animate attributeName="points" dur="500ms" to="M134.596,71.345c0.528,0.61,1.14,0.854,1.872,0.854c2.034,0,3.337-1.75,3.337-4.11
    c0-1.39-0.447-2.388-1.121-3.103c-1.497-1.587-4.112-1.781-5.431-1.781c-1.176,0-2.296,0.153-3.327,0.438
    c-1.031,0.285-1.973,0.702-2.791,1.23c-0.95,0.613-1.733,1.376-2.296,2.256c-0.633,0.988-0.987,2.124-0.987,3.36
    c0,0.583,0.079,1.132,0.223,1.656c0.075,0.277,0.168,0.546,0.277,0.81c0.345,0.833,0.845,1.606,1.428,2.351
    c0.316,0.404,0.657,0.801,1.011,1.194c0.952,1.061,1.999,2.103,2.915,3.236c1.396,1.725,2.489,3.657,2.489,6.177
    c0,0.744-0.094,1.42-0.27,2.023c-0.32,1.097-0.909,1.951-1.689,2.527c-0.762,0.563-1.707,0.862-2.762,0.862
    c-0.791,0-1.462-0.173-2.013-0.47c-0.501-0.271-0.902-0.645-1.205-1.086c-0.459-0.671-0.688-1.497-0.688-2.352
    c0-0.85,0.235-1.535,0.624-2.078c0.447-0.626,1.099-1.063,1.83-1.343c0.73-0.28,1.541-0.404,2.307-0.404
    c-0.122-2.116-2.156-2.686-3.581-2.686c-1.118,0-2.281,0.352-3.281,1.045c-0.773,0.536-1.448,1.276-1.93,2.216
    c-0.482,0.939-0.771,2.078-0.771,3.413c0,0.636,0.065,1.223,0.189,1.764c0.24,1.05,0.699,1.927,1.327,2.644
    c0.628,0.718,1.425,1.275,2.34,1.686c1.382,0.62,3.031,0.906,4.772,0.906c2.182,0,4.313-0.456,6.134-1.377
    c1.293-0.654,2.429-1.543,3.314-2.668c0.711-0.903,1.26-1.959,1.599-3.17c0.253-0.9,0.389-1.887,0.389-2.959
    c0-3.117-1.151-5.231-2.638-6.928c-1.269-1.448-2.78-2.593-4.029-3.799c-1.414-1.365-2.49-2.809-2.49-4.859
    c0-2.442,1.506-3.704,3.744-3.704s3.012,1.302,3.012,2.727C136.427,69.188,135.694,70.694,134.596,71.345z,M147.661,71.183c1.791,0,3.256-1.424,3.256-3.215c0-1.791-1.465-3.255-3.256-3.255
    s-3.215,1.465-3.215,3.255C144.446,69.758,145.87,71.183,147.661,71.183z,M189.499,90.024c-1.221,0-1.628-0.691-1.628-1.709c0-0.98,0.361-2.45,0.773-4.069
    c0.307-1.204,0.641-2.49,0.875-3.72c0.183-0.961,0.305-1.887,0.305-2.71c0-2.2-0.873-3.527-2.243-4.156
    c-0.657-0.302-1.429-0.443-2.273-0.443c-0.631,0-1.394,0.082-2.213,0.407c-0.819,0.326-1.694,0.896-2.549,1.872l0.448-2.116h-2.327
    h-1.833h-1.7l-0.469,2.216l-0.237,1.116l-0.891,4.2l-0.731,3.451l-0.441,2.08l0,0c-1.14,3.54-2.646,4.924-5.128,5.819l1.408-6.601
    l0.797-3.733l0.746-3.495l1.078-5.054h-5.86l-0.447,2.116v-0.244c0-1.18-0.978-2.076-3.297-2.076c-1.982,0-3.675,0.686-5.084,1.795
    c-1.29,1.015-2.343,2.383-3.164,3.904c-1.484,2.751-2.21,5.998-2.21,8.545c0,0.09,0.014,0.164,0.016,0.252
    c-0.27,0.506-0.588,0.961-0.953,1.326c-0.641,0.641-1.404,1.026-2.197,1.026c-1.14,0-1.669-0.366-1.669-1.506
    c0-0.366,0.041-0.773,0.163-1.302l2.93-13.837h-5.86l-2.767,13.063c-0.204,0.977-0.326,1.872-0.326,2.646
    c0,1.472,0.354,2.582,0.954,3.368c0.792,1.04,2.011,1.515,3.4,1.515c1.099,0,2.655-0.224,4.228-1.276
    c0.837-0.561,1.676-1.367,2.454-2.489c0.222,0.737,0.53,1.356,0.911,1.858c1.03,1.358,2.56,1.907,4.129,1.907
    c2.116,0,3.703-0.977,4.883-2.238l-0.488,2.157c-3.052,0.936-6.633,2.646-6.633,6.063c0,2.645,2.075,3.947,4.558,3.947
    c1.618,0,3.501-0.397,5.009-1.985c0.605-0.638,1.151-1.467,1.596-2.54c0.286-0.691,0.53-1.484,0.721-2.393l0.61-2.93
    c1.412-0.388,3.003-1.044,4.408-2.487l-0.139,0.655l-0.319,1.506h5.859l0.634-2.994l0.63-2.973l0.854-4.03l0.649-3.065
    c0.61-2.035,1.709-3.745,3.175-3.745c0.977,0,1.465,0.732,1.465,2.076c0,0.737-0.146,1.667-0.356,2.684
    c-0.175,0.842-0.393,1.743-0.606,2.645c-0.148,0.623-0.295,1.247-0.424,1.851c-0.256,1.194-0.444,2.312-0.444,3.198
    c0,0.802,0.117,1.6,0.399,2.3c0.317,0.789,0.846,1.454,1.654,1.862c0.549,0.277,1.227,0.437,2.056,0.437
    c0.865,0,1.697-0.203,2.407-0.635c0.603-0.367,1.117-0.898,1.49-1.611c0.283-0.542,0.484-1.188,0.579-1.945
    C190.598,89.943,190.191,90.024,189.499,90.024z M160.359,97.105c-0.2,0.909-0.465,1.649-0.763,2.218
    c-0.489,0.933-1.067,1.404-1.598,1.404c-0.896,0-1.384-0.773-1.384-1.344c0-0.814,0.479-1.486,1.218-2.051
    c0.737-0.563,1.733-1.021,2.771-1.407L160.359,97.105z M163.979,80.055l-0.875,4.063l-0.588,2.733
    c-0.569,2.075-2.156,3.174-3.255,3.174c-0.733,0-2.035-0.041-2.035-3.174c0-3.825,2.238-11.151,5.697-11.151
    c1.303,0,1.628,1.058,1.669,1.505L163.979,80.055z,M81.583,70.477c0-3.052-1.343-5.86-4.802-6.552c0.674-0.383,1.268-0.835,1.78-1.336
    c0.996-0.974,1.679-2.131,2.025-3.323c0.175-0.602,0.264-1.212,0.264-1.812c0-1.491-0.536-2.94-1.662-4.088
    c-0.375-0.383-0.816-0.732-1.325-1.038c-0.678-0.408-1.476-0.74-2.398-0.971c-0.958-0.24-2.051-0.373-3.283-0.373
    c-0.607,0-1.21,0.032-1.807,0.094c-1.187,0.124-2.345,0.366-3.451,0.708c-0.83,0.256-1.629,0.569-2.389,0.93
    c-0.323,0.153-0.638,0.315-0.945,0.486c-0.796,0.442-1.539,0.938-2.213,1.479c-0.547,0.439-1.049,0.907-1.499,1.4
    c-0.398,0.436-0.754,0.89-1.065,1.359c-0.377,0.57-0.687,1.163-0.917,1.77c-0.315,0.831-0.485,1.689-0.485,2.559
    c0,0.937,0.197,1.672,0.565,2.234c0.277,0.423,0.651,0.747,1.11,0.985c0.705,0.365,1.612,0.525,2.679,0.525
    c-0.041-0.366-0.57-0.692-0.57-2.767c0-1.822,0.398-3.383,1.074-4.691c0.47-0.91,1.075-1.698,1.773-2.365
    c1.996-1.908,4.756-2.833,7.327-2.833c3.866,0,5.372,2.076,5.372,4.395c0,3.052-2.604,6.593-5.86,6.593h-0.244l0.55-2.602
    l0.231-1.092l0.427-2.015l0.292-1.378l0.413-1.948l-3.161,0.427l-2.862,0.387l-0.399,1.869l-1.168,5.464l-0.348,1.628l-1.429,6.682
    l-0.45,2.105l-0.971,4.542l-0.769,3.592h2.176h3.684l0.8-3.735l0.651-3.039l0.473-2.208l0.624-2.914l0.79-3.691
    c0.732-0.081,1.546-0.122,1.872-0.122c2.69,0,3.678,1.903,3.841,4.378c0.017,0.258,0.025,0.522,0.025,0.791
    c0,0.976-0.105,2.065-0.343,3.1c-0.515,2.243-1.652,4.226-3.686,4.226c-0.936,0-1.709-0.407-2.727-1.465
    c-0.366,0.936-0.529,1.709-0.529,2.361c0,2.482,2.279,3.012,4.029,3.012C79.467,82.197,81.583,74.383,81.583,70.477z,M121.274,73.618l0.652-3.063l0.368-1.73l1.785-8.379l0.478-2.243l1.104-5.185l-6.023,0.814l-1.994,9.36
    v-0.163c0-1.18-0.977-2.076-3.296-2.076c-2.508,0-4.551,1.098-6.145,2.76c-1.478,1.541-2.568,3.566-3.283,5.651
    c-0.691,2.016-1.031,4.088-1.031,5.833c0,0.137,0.01,0.262,0.014,0.393c-0.643,1.404-1.569,2.456-2.783,2.456
    c-1.14,0-1.668-0.61-1.668-1.75c0-0.366,0.041-0.773,0.163-1.302l2.93-13.836h-5.86l-0.447,2.157v-0.285
    c0-1.18-0.977-2.076-3.296-2.076c-3.107,0-5.501,1.685-7.209,4.04c-2.185,3.012-3.249,7.121-3.249,10.204
    c0,1.408,0.224,2.551,0.609,3.465c0.939,2.228,2.841,3.087,4.803,3.087c2.89,0,4.802-1.872,6.063-3.744
    c0.068,0.683,0.232,1.275,0.482,1.776c0.645,1.291,1.864,1.968,3.506,1.968c1.675,0,4.2-0.528,6.333-3.714
    c0.831,2.689,2.888,3.714,5.022,3.714c2.686,0,4.558-1.628,5.779-3.377c0.488,2.359,2.157,3.377,4.232,3.377
    c2.197,0,4.273-1.302,4.477-4.191c-0.244,0.122-0.569,0.244-1.302,0.244c-1.262,0-1.669-0.692-1.669-1.628
    c0-0.366,0.081-0.773,0.163-1.18L121.274,73.618z M93.917,74.22c-0.488,2.36-2.197,3.582-3.377,3.582
    c-0.733,0-2.035-0.041-2.035-3.174c0-0.957,0.14-2.131,0.403-3.356c0.169-0.786,0.39-1.592,0.657-2.374
    c0.267-0.782,0.581-1.54,0.938-2.229c0.955-1.843,2.214-3.192,3.699-3.192c1.302,0,1.668,1.058,1.668,1.546L93.917,74.22z
     M115.121,74.872c-0.447,1.994-2.116,2.93-3.174,2.93c-0.733,0-2.035-0.041-2.035-3.174c0-3.825,2.238-11.15,5.698-11.15
    c1.221,0,1.587,0.936,1.668,1.424L115.121,74.872z,M80.768,51.467c-0.017-0.148-0.231-0.264-0.231-1.14c0-1.983,1.124-3.321,2.925-3.801l-0.545,2.181
    c-0.694,2.793-1.355,5.106-1.355,6.743c0,1.669,0.81,2.627,3.189,2.627c1.91,0,3.091-0.606,3.932-1.876
    c0.39-0.588,0.706-1.32,0.988-2.199c0.294-0.918,0.551-1.998,0.814-3.245l0.715-3.38l0.375-1.775h-2.33l-0.73,3.367l-0.377,1.74
    c-0.451,2.078-0.819,3.408-1.182,4.258c-0.58,1.361-1.144,1.493-2.008,1.493c-0.826,0-1.14-0.545-1.14-1.487
    c0-0.694,0.173-1.599,0.539-3.042s0.923-3.427,1.691-6.278c-0.347-0.066-0.512-0.083-0.793-0.083c-3.206,0-6.247,2.049-6.247,4.379
    C79,51.054,79.678,51.467,80.768,51.467z,M90.896,54.706l-0.69,3.255h2.379l0.375-1.768l0.509-2.402l0.241-1.135c0.248-0.826,0.694-1.52,1.289-1.52
    c0.396,0,0.595,0.297,0.595,0.843c0,1.058-0.744,3.09-0.744,4.214c0,0.942,0.512,1.867,1.95,1.867c0.661,0,1.547-0.201,2.34-1.462
    c0.347,1.057,1.169,1.462,2.023,1.462c1.173,0,1.95-0.76,2.446-1.521c0.132,0.926,0.727,1.421,1.62,1.421
    c0.681,0,1.707-0.158,2.574-1.426c0.341,1.065,1.219,1.525,2.418,1.525c1.647,0,2.849-0.863,3.745-1.936l-0.39,1.837h2.379
    l1.322-6.28c0.413-0.38,0.71-0.628,1.207-0.628c0.496,0,0.033,1.091,0.958,1.091c0.81,0,1.19-0.628,1.19-1.207
    c0-0.628-0.396-1.239-1.14-1.239c-0.793,0-1.421,0.529-2,1.024l0.215-1.024h-2.38l-1.125,5.305
    c-0.826,0.942-1.62,1.668-2.924,1.668c-0.793,0-1.19-0.264-1.19-1.388c0-0.198,0.017-0.43,0.033-0.661
    c1.983-0.116,3.801-1.586,3.801-3.487c0-0.827-0.347-1.586-1.818-1.586c-3.388,0-4.462,3.982-4.462,5.883
    c0,0.039,0.007,0.069,0.008,0.107c-0.261,0.546-0.638,0.917-1.132,0.917c-0.463,0-0.678-0.148-0.678-0.611
    c0-0.149,0.017-0.314,0.066-0.529l0.622-2.917l0.223-1.049l0.274-1.285l0.516-2.425l0.266-1.247l-2.445,0.331l-0.81,3.801v-0.066
    c0-0.479-0.396-0.843-1.338-0.843c-2.875,0-4.247,3.553-4.247,5.784c0,0.023,0.004,0.041,0.004,0.063
    c-0.287,0.599-0.594,0.995-1.179,0.995c-0.496,0-0.661-0.281-0.661-0.694c0-0.463,0.199-1.194,0.397-1.977s0.396-1.618,0.396-2.287
    c0-0.661-0.194-1.128-0.521-1.43c-0.327-0.301-0.785-0.438-1.314-0.438c-0.512,0-1.239,0.132-1.933,0.925l0.182-0.859h-2.38
    l-0.513,2.421L90.896,54.706z M112.236,50.426c0.314,0,0.413,0.265,0.413,0.678c0,1.372-1.124,2.644-2.396,2.727
    C110.583,52.194,111.394,50.426,112.236,50.426z M101.469,54.402c0.091-0.662,0.288-1.419,0.572-2.08
    c0.403-0.938,0.981-1.682,1.684-1.682c0.496,0,0.645,0.38,0.678,0.579l-0.81,3.784v0.083c-0.215,0.909-0.892,1.372-1.355,1.372
    c-0.297,0-0.826-0.017-0.826-1.289C101.411,54.939,101.431,54.679,101.469,54.402z,M53.918,80.987c1.168,0,1.958-0.773,2.451-1.53c0.131,0.954,0.724,1.53,1.612,1.53s1.201-0.51,1.645-1.661
    c-0.115,0.049-0.214,0.065-0.362,0.065c-0.46,0-0.674-0.148-0.674-0.608c0-0.148,0.016-0.313,0.065-0.526l0.255-1.205l0.468-2.209
    l0.236-1.116l0.225-1.063h-2.369l-0.181,0.872v-0.115c0-0.477-0.395-0.839-1." />
```

Does points are combined from many paths, but that doesn't work it's even not displaying anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are specifying the `points` attribute (which is for a `<polygon>` element), but you are passing it a `<path>` description (which should be a `d`).

So for a start, you will need to either change the `attributeName` or the `to` depending on which element you are trying to animate.

Also, the rule for animating paths is that they have to have the same number, and type, of path commands.  So you will need to modify either, or both, of the "from" and "to" paths so that they have the exact same number of lines and curves, and in the same order, in the path command.